# pgAdmin not retaining server connections

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, pgadmin

I'm using pgAdmin III 1.18.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. Whenever I reboot my machine, pgAdmin does not remember my server connections. If I enter the server connections and then close pgadmin3 and reopen, the server connections are retained, it is only when I reboot my machine that the connections are lost.

After I create my server connections and close pgAdmin I see that the `.pgadmin3` file is created just fine:

```
benc@Ubuntu-T7400:~$ ls -al | grep .pgadmin3
-rw-rw-r--   1 benc benc  2088 Mar 28 11:57 .pgadmin3
```

Restarting pgadmin3 will then display my server connections. But if I reboot my machine, my `.pgadmin3` file is set to 0 bytes.

After a reboot of Ubtuntu:

```
benc@Ubuntu-T7400:~$ ls -al | grep .pgadmin3
-rw-rw-r--   1 benc benc     0 Mar 28 12:10 .pgadmin3
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: I have the same issue only difference is that re-open also loose all connections, and I'm using ubuntu 14!

Answer (score 7):

I also gone through the same issue.  But I have fixed this issue by following.

1. Actually **.pgadmin3** file is missing from my home folder.  So, I created it manually.

   ```
   vish@Ubuntu:~$ ls -al | grep .pgadmin3
   -rw-rw-r--  1 vish vish          0 Jul 31 13:01 .pgadmin3
   ```
2. By default user will not have access to execute that file. So I gave full access rights on this file.

   ```
    vish@Ubuntu:~$ sudo chmod a+wx .pgadmin3
   ```

   So now it will look like:

   ```
   -rwxrwxrwx  1 vish vish          0 Jul 31 13:01 .pgadmin3
   ```

Now every thing is working good.

Comment: It's worth noting that on Ubuntu 14.04 (at least) `.pgadmin3` wasn't created for me in my home folder until I loaded pgadmin3 and closed out of it. Then I was able to use your fix while letting pgadmin populate that file first (instead of your step 1). Thanks!